# py-indent-or-complete, make hitting-tab in python mode move the cursor at first try

Tags: python-mode

when I press tab in python mode
`py-indent-or-complete` execute.

When I'm at a new line, it takes two `tab` keys for the cursor to move to a position.
I'd like to hit just `one` tab to do that.

eg) Suppose you type the bellowing

```
class A:
    1
    2
    *
```

and your cursor is at `*`.
Following shows next cursor locations

C-a (move to beginning of line)

```
class A:
    1
    2
*
```

Move up two lines (C-p, C-p)

```
class A:
*   1
    2
```

Now, hit tab, you need *two* tabs for your cursor to move to `1`

Comment: There's multiple python modes. In your question you should specify which one you're using. But, given the function you reference, I know it's [`python-mode.el`](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode)

Comment: Please provide some more clarity in your question. Where are you on a new line? How did you get there? Which direction do you want to move when you hit `Tab`?

Comment: @nega yes I'm using python-mode.el , I've added more context

Comment: much more clear, thanks. that is ... gross. unfortunately i've got nothing for you other than to file an issue at their gitlab. maybe someone else has a brighter idea